# Cannot add event listener to button. "Missing arguments for method ..."

Tags: scala, scala.js

I have a simple Scala.js app and am for some reason getting the error "Missing arguments for method onButtonClick(dom.MouseEvent)".

```
package main

import scalatags.JsDom.all._
import org.scalajs.dom.{MouseEvent, document}

import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExport

object Main extends js.JSApp {

  val boxA = input(
    `type` := "text",
    placeholder := "trust"
  ).render
  val boxB = input(
    `type` := "text",
    placeholder := "citation"
  ).render
  val b = button(
    placeholder := "Calculate"
    //, onclick := onButtonClick
  ).render

  def main(): Unit = {
    document.body.appendChild(div(h1("Hello, world"), boxA, boxB, b).render)
    b.addEventListener("onclick", onButtonClick)
  }

  def onButtonClick(event: MouseEvent): Unit = {
    println("click")
    println(boxA.value)
    println(boxB.value)
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You might need an explicit eta-expansion like this: `onButtonClick _`.

Comment: @sjrd Thanks, that worked. If you add an answer then I'll accept it, otherwise I'll make a community wiki answer

Answer (score 0):

You need an explicit eta-expansion like this: `onButtonClick _`

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, please accept it (even if it's a community answer written by you) so that other readers know this solves the problem.